# Find duplicates files and folders in directory and move the duplicates to different folders in python

Tags: python

I am very new to python and i am looking for help.
I am trying to find duplicate folders and files in a directory and move them to a different folder(called **Duplicates**)in the same directory and retain a single copy of all the files in a folder calles **Single_Copy**.I am able to find the duplicates and add their info in the CSV file but unable to **`create`** and move the files to Duplicates and Single_Copy folder.This piece of code is not showing the duplicated files properly.Could you please guide.
Please find my piece of code attached,

```
# checkDuplicates.py
# Python 2.7.6

"""
Given a folder, walk through all files within the folder and subfolders
and get list of all files that are duplicates
The md5 checcksum for each file will determine the duplicates
"""

import os
import hashlib
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

src_folder = "C://Users//renu//Desktop//SNow work related"
def generate_md5(fname, chunk_size=1024):
    """
    Function which takes a file name and returns md5 checksum of the file
    """
    hash = hashlib.md5()
    with open(fname, "rb") as f:
        # Read the 1st block of the file
        chunk = f.read(chunk_size)
        # Keep reading the file until the end and update hash
        while chunk:
            hash.update(chunk)
            chunk = f.read(chunk_size)

    # Return the hex checksum
    return hash.hexdigest()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """
    Starting block of script
    """

    # The dict will have a list as values
    md5_dict = defaultdict(list)

    file_types_inscope = ["ppt", "pptx", "pdf", "txt", "html",
                          "mp4", "jpg", "png", "xls", "xlsx", "xml",
                          "vsd", "py", "json"]

    # Walk through all files and folders within directory
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(src_folder):
        print("Analyzing {}".format(path))
        for each_file in files:
            if each_file.split(".")[-1].lower() in file_types_inscope:
                # The path variable gets updated for each subfolder
                file_path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(path), each_file)
                # If there are more files with same checksum append to list
                md5_dict[generate_md5(file_path)].append(file_path)

    # Identify keys (checksum) having more than one values (file names)
    duplicate_files = (
        val for key, val in md5_dict.items() if len(val) > 1)

    # Write the list of duplicate files to csv file
    with open("duplicates.csv", "w") as log:
        # Lineterminator added for windows as it inserts blank rows otherwise
        csv_writer = csv.writer(log, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, delimiter=",",
                                lineterminator="\n")
        header = ["File Names"]
        csv_writer.writerow(header)

        for file_name in duplicate_files:
            csv_writer.writerow(file_name)

    print("Done")
```

Comment: Why are you using Python 2.7.6? Not only is it a bad idea to keep using Python 2.7 unless you absolutely must, but the latest version of that is 2.7.18 (or .14 if your on Windows)

Comment: Your code creates a list of duplicates in a .csv file - are you literally only asking how to move a file from one location to another? Have you looked at `os.rename()` (on the same file system) or `shutil.move()` at all?

Comment: @Grismar I am not using Python 2.7.6.This is a continued work from a friend.I dont want a .csv file instead i want these files to be moved to different folders.the user can decide what to do with the duplicates.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? How about those standard library functions I asked about?

Comment: I am now looking into shutil.move()

Answer (score 0):

As @Grismar said, you can use the modules `os` or `shutil`.

```
import os
import shutil

os.rename("your/current/path/file.txt", "your/new/path/file.txt")
shutil.move("your/current/path/file.txt", "your/new/path/file.txt")
```

personal preference: `shutil`; because if you're on windows, os.rename will silently replace an existing file with the same name.

Comment: primarily i would wan to save the duplicates under a folder not in a csv file.how do i do that?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "not in a csv file". You just want to move *duplicateFile.csv* from one folder to another, right? `shutil.move` will move your *duplicateFile.csv" from the current folder to the new folder. You can also just do: `shutil.move("your/current/path/duplicate.csv", "your/new/path/"`

Comment: No.If you check the code i have posted it checks for the duplicate files and saves its path and name in a .csv file.instead i want the file itself to be moved into a destination.Say for eg file 1 is present in multiple folders it has to be moves under duplicates folder.be it any number of copies.

Comment: I think you should put some of the effort you're putting into telling other people what you want programmed into trying to program it yourself, @RENUMADHU - your question and comments show little to no evidence of actually writing any code, as you already indicated the code you provided was written by someone else. Please have a try and either update your question. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Grismar...Will take up the advice...thank you